# How to get my image responsive within the header??

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design

I can't for the life of me get an image to behave how I would like. The image should sit vertically within the parent div (Header) and be responsive. I want the whole thing to remain in proportion but at the moment that isn't happening. Can anyone please help?

```css
#headBar{
 background-color: #88a6cb;
    height: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}


#menubutton{
 height: 70%;
    float: right; 
    padding-right: 5%;
    margin:auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="headBar">
  <a href="javascript:ReverseDisplay('dropmen')">
  <img id="menubutton" src="https://lh3.ggpht.com/XkKFmevjtyDntd5e0XeSssV1fukxNFuMvXRpMdXGZ56Ev5WPpggPrPFEi_2AUXFMbd4=w300"/>
  </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: i am not sure vertical-align works well with floats !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `top` together with [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform). `top` will position the circle at 50% the height of it's parent, `translateY` will position relative to itself, so -50% of the circles height:

```
#menubutton{
    height: 70%;
    float: right; 
    padding-right: 5%;
    margin:auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;

    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/x9gh4xzz/2/)

Note: http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d